# Query results that are NOT IN another table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a script that will search in a table for artist names that doesnt match the artist name from another table

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT artist FROM artists WHERE artist NOT IN (select artist from singer) LIMIT 4") or die(mysql_error());
```

After it runs it inserts the artist in to singer table, then if i run it again it will come back saying no results instead of skipping by the first 4 artists in the artists table because they are in the singer table and grabbing the next 4

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: this is because you `LIMIT` your result to 4 so next run singers won't match your `NOT IN` clause as they are `IN`

Comment: Yeah but i don't want to run it without a limit, is there a way i can skip by the ones that are in the singer table and move on to the next 4

Comment: Don't use mysql_* functions - they are deprecated!

Comment: If it returns you no results that means you have all the artists in singer table , pls check that

Comment: Of course i have checked the singers table lol

Comment: for the second run try `LIMIT 4,4` for the third `LIMIT 8,4` and so on...

Comment: Where is the `INSERT` statement?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your `SELECT` statement. This [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d94df/3) proves that. With the commented `INSERT` statements at the bottom of the schema section it returns the first four viable records **(as expected)**. Then, if you uncomment those lines and rebuild the schema you will find that it returns the next four viable records **(as expected)**.

So, if you are in fact issuing an `INSERT` for the four that are retrieved **after** gathering them but **before** asking for more then there is **something wrong with the `INSERT` statement.**

In contrast though, if you are **not** issuing the `INSERT` into `singer` **before** asking for more then you'll need a more dynamic SQL statement, and the Fiddle shows that statement (albeit statically) as well. The PHP for a more dynamic statement might look like this:

```
$offset = 0;
$sql = true;

while ($sql) {
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT artist FROM artists WHERE artist NOT IN (select artist from singer) LIMIT $offset, 4") or die(mysql_error());
    $offset += 4;
}
```

Comment: That is causing the page to never load, at the bottom of the page i have an insert that inserts the 4 singers that it gatherd. but if i stop the script and restart it, instead of it bypassing the first 4 rows from artist(because they are in the singers table) and gathering a new 4, it just return saying no results